# Android: Search resource in default strings file

Tags: android

I have a procedure for retrieving the amount of resources by a prefix:

```
private int countResources(String prefix, String type) {
    long id = -1;
    int count = -1;
    while (id != 0) {
        count++;
        id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(prefix + (count + 1),
                type, getPackageName());
    }

    return count;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
int maxItems = countResources(titlePrefix, "string");
```

I can do that with `string`, `drawable`, `color` etc.

With strings it counts all possible encounters, fx. if `strings.xml`contains 1 qualifying element and `strings.xml (fr)` includes 2 elements, the the result of this procedure will be 2.

I would only like this procedure to only count in the default `strings.xml` resource file and not the other translations.

Any ideas?